# Can macOS preview CSS files?

Tags: macos, finder, bug, quicklook

I was surprised that when I select a CSS file and press the Space bar, there is no preview and instead an error.

> The extension com.apple.tips.TipsAppQuicklook-macOS does not implement file previews.

[image]

Is it a bug or what?

Ventura 13.5.1

upd. The folder `com.apple.tips.TipsAppQuicklook-macOS` in `~/Library/Application Scripts` is empty.

Comment: CSS files are text files with the `.css` extension and currently QL doesn't support this.

Comment: @Allan This so strange. QL supports, for example, Markdown and JavaScript files. What might be special about CSS?

Comment: Well yes, but those are likely associated with an app that provided the QL plugin.  Remember, CSS files are associated with a web browser, by default.

Comment: Well, thanks. Out of curiosity, could you check the `~/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.tips.TipsAppQuicklook-macOS` folder on your Mac? Is it empty?

Comment: Mine’s empty.  There might be. QL viewer on GitHub.  See the second answer in the dupe